# In IE8, glitches during jQuery slider transition

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Would someome do a quick check on IE 8 and go to my site and verify that what I'm seeing is correct? I've been coding a new stylesheet for IE8 and it works fine, except all of the sudden I am now getting some pixelation glitch in the top left thumbnail of my homepage slider. This wasn't there a moment ago and I haven't changed anything, so I want to make sure it's a bug on my computer and not in IE 8.

http://fdoandsons.com/beta/index.html

What I see:

Top left thumbnail on the above link flashes black squares when the slider is transitioning. You can view in a standards compliant browser and see what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Update your graphics drivers?

Comment: Working here to, probably just your computer